# cordova run android command fails with Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to run an app in my linux mint 17.3 Rosa using the following command

```
 cordova run android
```

But I everytime I run this I get the following error

```
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier
  /node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
            throw err;
            ^

 Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/mahesh/.config/configstore
 /update-notifier-cordova.json'
 You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules
/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules
/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules
/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules   
/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
at checkForUpdates (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:64:20)
at cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:114:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/
bin/cordova:41:1)
```

I dont Know how to proceed further.Can anyone help me out.Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: Did you have to install `node` using `sudo`? You could check that your [npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) are set correctly. Alternatively, you may also need to change ownership of the project files (search `chown` and then `chmod` if you're unfamiliar with this process).

Answer (score 0):

I Got the same error and i fixed it by following the Solution1 , you can try Solution1 or other Solutions to overcome this issue

Solution1 : Try to uninstall cordova and reinstall it

Solution2 : Install bower_components and reintall cordova android

Solution3 : 
You can fix this problem using one of three options:

1: Change the permission to npm's default directory

1).Find the path to npm's directory:

```
npm config get prefix
```

For many systems, this will be /usr/local.

WARNING: If the displayed path is just /usr, switch to Option 2 or you will mess up your permissions.

2).Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user (your username!):

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (lib/node_modules, bin, and share).

2: Change npm's default directory to another directory

There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the default directory that npm uses (i.e. /usr) as this could cause some problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.

Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home folder.

1).Make a directory for global installations:

mkdir ~/.npm-global
2).Configure npm to use the new directory path:

npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
3).Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
4).Back on the command line, update your system variables:

source ~/.profile
Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

npm install -g jshint
nstead of steps 2-4 you can also use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
3: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you.

sets things up out of the box with the correct permissions.

brew install node